# My PC has corrupted files after a windows 10 reset

Tags: windows-10

My PC was fine but I had lots of random files and wanted a full reset so I did a full wipe on my pc and download windows 10 through a usb and now I run into so many problems such as random blue screens, corrupted files, games don’t download properly and when I browse on chrome i would get errors like status_access_violation and status_breakpoint.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did those random files have names like `File0001.chk`?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you ran a Repair Install (not a full, delete everything reset), used the default Keep Everything. This is what the onboard Windows Reset does by default.

You probably have a damaged user profile or other very serious OS damage.

Back up all your documents onto an external drive. Make sure of this.

Then use the Microsoft Windows ISO, install Windows, and at the appropriate time in the setup, Keep Nothing (uncheck both boxes to keep Apps and keep Data).

Also consider formatting the drive and doing a completely fresh install.

Of course, run Hardware Diagnostics on the disk to make sure it is good and free of errors.

A failing disk could still result in corrupted files after a fresh install.

Comment: Hey John, I currently have nothing on my PC as I did a reset before so should I be fine to reinstall windows?

Comment: Given your post, yes, you should be fine to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Hey John, should I install windows through usb or iso file

Comment: You can can put the MIcrosoft ISO on your computer. Microsoft Media Creation Link. It will put itself in a folder. Go to the folder, run Setup and do not keep any Apps or Data - Keep Nothing.

Comment: Ok thanks John, I will update you  if everything goes well.

Comment: Hey John, I keep getting this error code when I try install windows.  The installation failed in the safe_os phase with an error during apply_image operation

Comment: Ok I managed to install windows but I ran a sfc scannow and it still came up with corrupted files

Comment: Are you really certain you used the option to Keep Nothing?  I do not see how that could lead to corrupted files unless the disk is bad.  Do run hardware diagnostics on the drive.  I noted that in my answer

Comment: @bananaman a Reset should only be used when the machine is being sold/given away. A repair install should be used if Windows still boots, else a clean install should be done if repairing the boot files doesn't work.  There is no _safe_os_ step of the Windows install - please add to your question the info included in your comments, especially the _exact_ messages you're seeing.

Comment: @John It can't lead to corrupted files

Comment: You are correct, so bananaman  ....  Either make sure you did a fresh install as I posted (Keep Nothing or else format the drive)  and / or check the disk for errors.

Comment: I am 100% I pressed Keep Nothing, how do i run a hardware diagnostics?

Comment: You should look up the disk manufacturer and get the hardware diagnostics for the drive.  If you did a fresh install (nothing kept) and you still have corrupted files then the disk may be failing.

Comment: Hey John and JW, Appreciate the help but you guys were right, I looked up a tutorial on how to check for hardware problems and there were, so I just brought it in the tech shop. All that stress and time wasted just to realise it was a hardware issue. Learn from your mistakes i guess...

Comment: You might consider accepting my answer to close the question